# How to delete the channels of a category deleted by the user on Discord?

Tags: discord, categories, discord.py, channel

I want to delete all channels of a category deleted by the user on Discord, using python.
I've just found this function on_guild_channel_delete(channel) but it doesn't work as I want cause the channels are found after the category was deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more and what've you already tried?

Comment: Yes sure!
I'm using this function:
`@commands.Cog.listener("on_guild_channel_delete")
    async def on_guild_channel_delete(self,channel):
        if type(channel) == CategoryChannel and channel.name == "CATEGORY NAME":
            channels = channel.channels
            for chan in channels:
                await chan.delete()
`
but this one doesn't delete the channels of the deleted category, cause the channels are already free.
What I want is to delete the channels of specific deleted category by user

Comment: Will you use that bot in your own server or is this will be a public bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use that bot on your own server and if all of your channels will be in any category, you can use that way:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    for chn in channel.guild.channels:
        if not chn.category and not isinstance(chn, discord.channel.CategoryChannel):
            await i.delete()
```

With this, it will delete all the channels that has no category when a category or channel is deleted. This isn't a perfect solution but as far as I know, this is the only way to do this.

Comment: @Mr.Wrecker https://gyazo.com/5b00bf58faa935f39a4d2d3435e92931